# Send data to frontend expressjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, frontend, backend

I'm using Nodejs, expressjs, sqlite3.

I have managed to get my data from database and route using expressjs, this is all in a js file called server.js

Now I want to send/use the data I have extracted in the front end.

I tried to have a global variable and use that global variable in other js files but that didn't work. After some research, I see AJAX most of the time. Do I need to use AJAX to send my data from backend to frontend?

The idea is to update frontend based on what product the user selects. I get the product data in server js, I don't know how to send it to frontend to fill in tables and change name of product based on the data on the database.

Also, should I continue and see if saving/using my data in a global variable works? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is a great way to request data from the back end without triggering a full page reload.  However it adds a layer of complexity that it doesn't sound like you need.  Since you're using express you get access to a [templating engine](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) out of the box that can handle this for you.

The express response object has a [render](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render) method where you specify the template to use, and the data to send to the template.  Some pseudo code for you:

```
// server.js
app.get('someroute',(req,res,next)=>{
    //get data from DB, returns promise
    return db.getData().then((data)=>{
        return res.render('myTableTemplate',data);
    });
});
```

In the template file, you would populate the table with the JSON data appropriately.

If you are using a client side JS library (react, vue, angular, etc.) you can skip `res.render(...)` and simply `res.json(data)`

Comment: I'm using html for my views. How do I select which element/attribute to be mapped with my data? Also, how do I change the view to show detail of that specific item? E.g. when a element in a table is clicked, go to a different view and modify the element/attribute values based on the data for that specific item (It's a product in my case).

Comment: Here is what I have:
         app.render( "/productDetail.html",rows, function(err, html) {
                console.log(rows);
                res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/projectDetail.html'));
            }); Say I want to do map product name to rows.productName. How can I do that in so I see the correct product name when that product is selected in the home page.                 //document.getElementById('pname') = rows.productName; something like for example

Comment: The syntax to map data to your table is highly dependent on the templating engine you are using. That should be defined before your routes. Something like `app.set('engine','ejs')`. You don't do res.sendFile in the render function callback. Render will create the html based on the data and send to client.

Comment: @asker if the answers helped you please mark one of the responses as the answer to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should create RESTful APIs to do what you want. This means you have to use AJAX and you can't work with global varibles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to redirect the page using AJAX? E.g. when a element in a table is clicked, go to a different view and modify the element/attribute values based on the data for that specific item (It's a product in my case).

Comment: Yes, let's say you have your site `www.yoursite.com` with a page `/products`, from this page you can redirect to a page `/product/id_product` where the `id_product` could be the primary key you use in a sqlite3 table of products.

Answer (score 0):

Use a WebSocket

WebSocket is probably the way to go: https://socket.io/

from backend you just need to emit the payload